# Choose specific kind of hosting service for WordPress?

Tags: hosting

I am going to start my own website soon. Right now I am looking for hosts. However some hosts say they support WordPress (or that they are *WordPress hosts*)

Do I have to pick such a hosting service or would WordPress work on any kind of hosting services that meets requirements (PHP version etc.) ?

Comment: If you want to develop a site for free, before you go LIVE, then check out https://pantheon.io or https://c9.io.

Comment: @jgraup Looks solid! Going to check them now. Thank you!

Comment: Pantheon let's you have a Dev, Test and Live environment and uses Git + SSH. Even if you don't end up using them for your final solution you'll have great WP support.

Comment: @jgraup I won't lie I really don't know a lot about website building. I can say that I have to take a extremely-quickened-self-learning-class in two days. I have a custom WP theme I bought, and I need to set a WP site and install the theme. All within two days from now on.

Comment: You should be prepared to pay for descend hosting. Minimum requirements should never be a benchmark. WordPress only requires PHP 5.2.something, which is a dinosaur version. Any host worth its salt should be running PHP 5.6. When it comes to resources and caps, always think of worst case scenario, and when you hit that worst case scenario, will your host be able to produce and keep your site live without a visitor noticing that your site is running into some issues due to some problem.

Comment: @PieterGoosen I am ready to pay for whatever is needed. I just don't want to waste my time and motivation with bad choices head on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress will run on a toaster these days, it really doesn't have high requirements. Just make sure it's a Linux server, any comapny worth anything will have PHP and mySQL up to date enough for WordPress.

What your're going to have to struggle with is different companies offering different packages and then not being fully honest. A mid range package on one service may be worse than the cheapest offered by another because they sneakily overload their servers.

Remember than even on the "cloud" your site still runs on a piece of hardware that is going to be getting shared with others unless you jump onto a dedicated server off the bat.

My advice is always do your research on the company and reviews, don't go in for a long term contract and be prepared to jump ship if you don't get the service you need.

Remember that WordPress has a lot of plugins for caching and speeding up sites, these usually also come ready to tie into Content Delivery Networks that can help take the burden of delivering your site to your viewers as well which means a slow server don't impact your users anywhere near as much as without a CDN.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your reply. I know recommendations are off topic but do you have any experience with GoDaddy? Or any references? I actually think of going in with them for the hosting.

Comment: I've worked with a lot of clients who have used them before moving onto our dedicated servers. From what I've seen and heard they can be both good and bad. I've assumed they have good emptier clusters and busier clusters, so users experiences differ. That said you could go a lot worse. Remember that marketing is a big thing for server companies. I've personally used some very nice looking sites for my personal project hosting that have in the end had horrible servers.

Comment: What are "your dedicated servers" ?

Comment: GoDaddy is hell when it comes to shared hosting and WordPress. I'd get a provider that gives you a proper cPanel and lets you edit PHP execution time and memory limits.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary. WordPress will work, as you say, on any kind of hosting service that meets requirements. But...It can be advantage. WordPress supporting hosts server should be ideally configured, contains all necessary extensions for the most common plugins and customer support might be familiar with WordPress and can help you with your potential problems.

Answer (score 0):

The requirements for WordPress can be found [here](https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/).

They recommend the following and most respectable hosting providers have these:

> - PHP 5.6 or greater
> - MySQL 5.6 or greater
> - The mod_rewrite Apache module

---

[WP Engine](https://wpengine.com), [WordPress VIP](https://vip.wordpress.com) and [Pantheon.io](https://pantheon.io), [WordPress.com](https://wordpress.com), [Media Temple.net](https://mediatemple.net) are all WP Hosting solutions. That means they tailor their services to WP solutions and you will get faster and more reliable support for the platform as well as servers optimized for WP. The drawback is that you might lose power features like SSH or WP-CLI which can be a plus for some people that don’t want to think about server issues.

Sites like [Dreamhost](https://www.dreamhost.com) & [c9.io](https://c9.io) will be cheaper and you'll have greater flexibility in what you do with the server but WordPress is only 1 of many features they offer.

I’ve heard a lot of great things about WPVIP and WPEngine.

---

Aside from the suggestions of live solutions like [Pantheon.io](https://pantheon.io) and [C9.io](https://c9.io) you might want to consider what you're running locally for development.

If you're going to be learning to build a WordPress website I highly recommend using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com). It's quick to setup and great to work with. Paired with [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org) it'll run in the background and symlinks files in a folder.

To get started make sure you follow the [requirements](https://github.com/ideasonpurpose/basic-wordpress-vagrant#requirements) by installing [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/), [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/), [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com) via [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/) and [vagrant-hostmanager](https://github.com/smdahlen/vagrant-hostmanager) to top it off.

```
> brew install ansible
> vagrant plugin install vagrant-hostmanager
```

Download the project https://github.com/ideasonpurpose/basic-wordpress-vagrant and unzip to a folder called `/basic-dev/`. Place a fresh [WordPress](https://wordpress.org/latest.zip) in the root and rename the WP folder to `/site`.

```
basic.dev/  < vagrant up
  └──site/  < wordpress files
```

Run `vagrant up` in the root directory.

That's it. It should take about 50~ seconds depending on your machine to create the environment. From here on out, all the database setup is handled through Ansible and new WordPress environments are created as easy as unzipping those two files in the right directories.

If you added the `vagrant-hostmanager` then you can access your site at `http://basic.dev/` after `vagrant up`. If you shutdown your computer, run `vagrant up` again to bring it back online.

Slides on the project are up on [SlideShare](http://www.slideshare.net/joemaller/wordpress-vagrant).

### UPDATE:

I created a Bash Snippet to automate a new environment - [New Vagrant Box with Latest WordPress](https://codepad.co/snippet/x9TwyHwH).  It boils a fresh VM of WordPress down to:

```
./new_vagrant.sh $NAME
```

---

I mention all this because being able to test things without breaking your main site will help you learn faster without restrictions. Breaking a live site sucks.